# Python graph not plot

Tags: python-2.7

i read datas from csv file and plot a graph from column A and D.
column A have a date format (dd/mm/yy), 
column D have a value format (xx.xx)
Code bellow

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import csv

csv_file = open('indice.csv')

reader = csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
next(reader)
next(reader)
next(reader)


for row in reader:
    a = row[0]
    b = row[4]
    from datetime import datetime
    x = [datetime.strptime(a, '%d/%m/%Y').date()]
    y = float(b)
    print(x, y)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(md.DayLocator())
plt.plot(x, y,)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()

csv_file.close()
```

The graph don't mach the date with value and no line

[image: the graph don't mach the date with value and no line]

What i see in console

[image: what i see in console]

Comment: It would be nice, if you could add the error log as quoted text to the question.

Comment: there is no error only "Process finished with exit code 0" and it open the graph and i can see also in console the two columns that it read.

Comment: any idea ? please